# How to Fill TextBoxes from DataGridView on Button Click Event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to fill data on button click event from DataGridView Control:

[image]

My code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_EmpAttList.Columns.Count; i++)
{
  txt_EnrollNo.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
  txt_FirstInTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
  txt_LastOutTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
  txt_TotalHours.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What? Which code are you using? Pick one, you cant have both!

Comment: What's the problem? Are you even getting one?

Comment: Are you mistaken .net and vb.net? .net is a framework and c# and vb.net is different languishes witch is possible to write in .net with. vb.net is named vb.net to not be mistaken with vb an earlier version who aint a part of the .net framework.

Comment: i am getting only single value on single click event and save values but i want get all different value on click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through your columns probably won't help here.

Try assigning each textbox the cell that it is mapped to:

```
txt_EnrollNo.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
txt_FirstInTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: ok but getting error ::     An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @Jig12 Make sure you error check that you have a CurrentRow selected, and that your Cells index match your columns index.

Comment: now i got it but i getting value on single grid view row on one click but i want all values next by next on clik event

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to use looping? Simply you can write

```
 txt_EnrollNo.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
txt_FirstInTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
txt_LastOutTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
 txt_TotalHours.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

EDIT:

Then on Button click send the row to update and write the code as follows

```
txt_EnrollNo.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //where row is DataGridViewRow
```

Comment: ok but i want to fill all datagridview records one by one show on textboxes on click event. This is code only fetch one row records only so

Comment: i got error ::: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in JERP2010.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: May be you dint initialized some object of a Class, can you edit your post and paste the modified code here so that i will see where will be the Exception.

Comment: HOW CAN I ASK QUESTION BECAUSE SOME ERROR IS OCCURING  LIKE THIS "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."