# how to Fill TextBoxes from DataGridView on button click event in VB.net using c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Fill TextBoxes from DataGridView on Button Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754569/how-to-fill-textboxes-from-datagridview-on-button-click-event)

i want to fill texboxes from DataGridView row one by one on button click event using vb.net with c#?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_EmpAttList.Columns.Count; i++)
{

       txt_EnrollNo.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       txt_FirstInTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       txt_LastOutTime.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       txt_TotalHours.Text = this.dgv_EmpAttList.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```